# Error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')", before was working

Tags: api, undefined, face-detection, clarifai

About one month ago I deploy react app, frontend on github, backend and database on heroku ("smartbrain" project from udemy Zero to Mastery). All was working good till now. About six days ago I checked if stil is working and all was perfect. 10 hours ago I recieved an email with info about knex 2.3.0 on backend server have issue of security and I need to update to 2.4.0, I did that, I checked if it works after this procedure but there was already an error. Then again I downgrade knex, but still is same error. Also I checked code of my teacher from course and there also is the same problem. Some one have any idea what happen?

That app is connecting to Clarifai Face Detection Api.

Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at App.calcFaceLocation (App.js:47:1)
at App.js:92:1

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import Navigation from './Components/Navigation/Navigation';
import SignIn from './Components/SignIn/SignIn';
import Register from './Components/Register/Register';
import Logo from './Components/Logo/Logo'
import ImgLinkForm from './Components/ImgLinkForm/ImgLinkForm';
import FaceRecognition from './Components/FaceRecognition/FaceRecognition';
import Rank from './Components/Rank/Rank';
import Particles from './Components/Particles/Particles';
import './App.css';


const initialState = {
  input: '',
  imageUrl:'',
  box:{},
  route:'signin',
  isSignedIn: false,
  user: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    entries: 0,
    joined: ''
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = initialState;
  }

  loadUser = (data) => {
    this.setState({user: {
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      email: data.email,
      entries: data.entries,
      joined: data.joined
    }})
  }
  
  calcFaceLocation = (data) => {
    const clarifaiFace = data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
    const image = document.getElementById('inputimage');
    const width = Number(image.width);
    const height = Number(image.height);
    return {
      leftCol: clarifaiFace.left_col * width,
      topRow: clarifaiFace.top_row * height,
      rightCol: width - (clarifaiFace.right_col * width),
      bottomRow: height - (clarifaiFace.bottom_row * height)
    }
  }

  dispFaceBox = (box) => {
    this.setState({box: box})
  }

  onInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({input: e.target.value})
  }

  onPictureSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input});
    fetch('https://smart-brain-api-db.herokuapp.com/imageurl', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        input: this.state.input
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      if(response) {
        fetch('https://smart-brain-api-db.herokuapp.com/image',{
          method: 'put',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({
            id: this.state.user.id
          })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(count => {
          this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: count }))
        })
        .catch(console.log)
      }
      this.dispFaceBox(this.calcFaceLocation(response))
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  onRouteChange = (route) => {
    if (route === 'signout') {
      this.setState(initialState)
    } else if (route === 'home') {
      this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
    }
    this.setState({route: route})
  }

  render() {
    const { isSignedIn, imageUrl, route, box } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="particles">
          <Particles />
        </div>
        <Navigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
        { route === 'home'
        ? <div> 
        <Logo />
        <Rank name={this.state.user.name} entries={this.state.user.entries}/>
        <ImgLinkForm onInputChange={this.onInputChange} onPictureSubmit={this.onPictureSubmit}/>
        <FaceRecognition box={box} imageUrl={imageUrl}/>
      </div>
        : ( 
        route === 'signin'
        ? <SignIn loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
        : <Register loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

About 6 hours I'm using all solutions what I find on google, but no effect. Even I didn't find anything similar. If I need to upload any file more please write me that and I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems not be an issue related to your implementation of the Clarifai API. To fix such an error, you may need to check that the value is not undefined before accessing the property.

Comment: Do you can explain more? Or give me an example how to check that?

Comment: If you check Clarifai's documentation, you can learn how to implement the API. Just grab the JavaScript (REST) samples and use them in your REACT project.

Comment: I did that project in react, and I tried both options to implement api, with predict way I get that error from above, with grpc apper another error throwed by my backend server "Received failed status: Model does not exist
Model 'a403429f2ddf4b49b307e318f00e528b' does not exist."

Comment: If a model does not exist, it exactly means that: you've not referenced an existing model. You need to refer to a model that exists--either from Clarifai or the one you've created on your own.

Comment: Yeah I understand error, the thing is, in one day all face detect models aren't existing? I tried all models which I find on clarifai. Before that errors appers all was working good. Second thing is on clarifai test model section at least one exist and work good, when I try to use this working model, throw same errors like above in both ways of implementation. In 4 january they made some update, maybe something went wrong on clarifai side.